# Pulling data from same table twice with different keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have written a SQL query and it works but I can't seem to get it to work if I try to pull data from the same table twice in the same query.

Here is my query

```
SELECT
wp_postmeta.meta_value as selger,
wp_postmeta.meta_value as club,
sum(num_items_sold) as solgt_lodd
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_wc_order_stats 
ON wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_postmeta.meta_value
AND meta_key = "_velg_club" AND meta_key = "_selger_navn"  AND post_id = wp_wc_order_stats.order_id AND wp_wc_order_stats.status != "wc-refunded" and wp_wc_order_stats.status != "wc-cancelled" and  wp_wc_order_stats.status != "trash" 
group by selger
Order BY selger ASC
```

This doesn't cause an error but it also doesn't show results. But if I, let's say, remove either `club` or `selger`, it will work. What am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to get results from `wp_postmeta.meta_value` twice with two different keys. A result should look like the following:

| NAME | CLUB | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | MC | Club 2 |
| Jane | MC | Club 5 |

Comment: *`.. meta_key = "_velg_club" AND meta_key = "_selger_navn" ..`* Do you really hope to find a row where one column contains two different values?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), pp. 5 and 3.

Comment: `wp_postmeta.meta_value = wp_postmeta.meta_value` this is a quite interesting join condition when you join the same table on itself on the very same field. This will create quite a few duplicates in the output.